# Infinite scrolling background on libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, infinite-scroll

I am trying to do an infinite scrolling background on libgdx.The image is scrolling fine in the X-axis, but in the Y-axis the image is split in half like shown in the picture below. How can I get the ground to start at the bottom of the screen? [image]

Here is my code

```
    package com.tashtoons.game.States;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.tashtoons.game.BuckyRun;
import static com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat;



public class PlaySate extends State {
    private Texture bg;
    float sourceX = 0;

    public PlaySate(GameStateManager gsm) {
        super(gsm);
       bg=new Texture("bg.png");
       cam.setToOrtho(false,BuckyRun.WIDTH/2,BuckyRun.HEIGHT/2);
        bg.setWrap(Repeat,Repeat);
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleInput() {

    }

    @Override
    public void update(float dt) {

    }

    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
        sourceX += 10;
        sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        sb.begin();
        sourceX = (sourceX + Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() / 3/4) % bg.getWidth();
        sb.draw(bg, 0, 0, (int) sourceX, 0,BuckyRun.WIDTH, BuckyRun.HEIGHT);
        sb.end();

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass to `cam.setToOrtho()` viewport width and height.
Also you probably want to correct the code for drawing the texture (left comments in the code):

```
public class PlaySate extends State {
    private Texture bg;
    float sourceX = 0;

    public PlaySate(GameStateManager gsm) {
        super(gsm);
       bg=new Texture("bg.png");
       cam.setToOrtho(false,BuckyRun.WIDTH,BuckyRun.HEIGHT); // edited this
        bg.setWrap(Repeat,Repeat);
    }


    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
        sourceX += 10;
        sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        sb.begin();

        // this line doesn't make much sense, you've already incremented sourceX, 
        // "Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() / 3/4" especially confuses me
        // why sourceX =% bg.getWidth(); isn't enough?
        sourceX = (sourceX + Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() / 3/4) % bg.getWidth();

        // you probably want to draw texture in full screen
        sb.draw(bg,
               // position and size of texture
               0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 
               // srcX, srcY, srcWidth, srcHeight
               (int) sourceX, 0, bg.getWidth(), bg.getHeight(),
               // flipX, flipY
               false, false);
        sb.end();

    }
}
```

**Update**

Instead of these two lines:

```
sourceX += 10;
...
sourceX = (sourceX + Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() / 3/4) % bg.getWidth();
...
```

there should be only one:

```
sourceX = (sourceX + Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * velocity) % bg.getWidth();
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: About that line with "Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() / 3/4". Why do you divide by 3/4? Incrementing sourceX should look like this: `sourceX = (sourceX + Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * velocity) % bg.getWidth();`